# Tool for writing document about the REST Web Services like WSDL?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jersey

Is there any tool for writing document about the REST Web Services like WSDL? I need to write about the web services many times. I need to write about the URI, required parameters, response and method type. So is there any tool by which i can prepare such kind of doc. I use only online Microsoft Excel Creator tool. I need some tool which is specifically for this thing only.

Comment: Have a look at Swagger
http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you will need to make at least a few adjustments to your existing code / organisation / development. Possible tools for the job are

- Raml ( http://raml.org )
- Spring REST Docs ( http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/ )

there are quite a few more if you google ( swagger, ApiDocJS ..etc)